# How do I use AWS sdk definitions for TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, typescript

I am trying to write an SES TypeScript client, using AWS definitions file downloaded from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/aws-sdk/aws-sdk.d.ts

Here is what I've tried:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/aws-sdk.d.ts" />
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
var ses:SES = new AWS.SES();
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/tsc --sourcemap SesTest.ts
SesTest.ts(3,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SES'.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I cannot find any documentation on how to make this work. Please help!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think a more appropriate way to do this is

`import { <ServiceName> } from 'aws-sdk';`

for instance

`import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';`

followed by

`this.client = new DynamoDB();` in the class.

I say it is more appropriate because it uses TypeScript's import syntax.

Also, there's a clear explanation - by AWS - on how to use [TS with AWS SDK here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/#Usage_with_TypeScript).

Comment: This should be the best answer and preferred approach.

Comment: This fails to compile with "has no exported member"

Comment: This should be `import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';`, note the capitalized ..DB

Answer (score 16):

Change to :

```
import AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
var ses:AWS.SES = new AWS.SES();
```

Note: if `import` is unclear you probably want to read up on modules : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

TIP: always a good idea to see the test file for intended usage : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/aws-sdk/aws-sdk-tests.ts

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful and it did solve my immediate problem, but now I'm stuck trying to use the actual type definitions. For instance, how do I create a new Destination object? I tried 'var dest = new AWS.Ses.Destination();' but I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Destination' of undefined

Comment: `var dest = new AWS.Ses.Destination();` the definitions might be wrong (they are best effort ... as is any documentation). Use a type assertion to coerce it : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you said, and I don't understand the problem well enough to know how use type assertions to fix it. I'll just go back to JavaScript for this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, @basarat! Looks like your test file link is now dead.  May want to update it!