# How to import/integrate amazon aws-sdk to ionic2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, ionic2, aws-sdk, typescript-typings

Ionic2 is Typescript based, and Amazon is providing javascript only version of its library.

Is it possible to integrate the Amazon aws-sdk into an Ionic2 app?

I have tried multiple methods including creating a typings file (and tsd), and trying to work out [aws-cognito-angular2-quickstart](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular2-quickstart.git) but no luck so far...

Is creating an external javascript library and integrating it into the typescript code my only option?

Has anyone succeeded using Amazon Cognito from Ionic2 app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add typescript definitions of the AWS-SDK in your ionic2 and/or angular2 app. This will allow you to use all build-in functionalities provided in the AWS-SDK including Cognito.
Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225183/how-do-i-use-aws-sdk-definitions-for-typescript) to get started.

Comment: nope... That's the wrong way to do that, since there are no UPDATED "definitely typed" typescript wrapper for AWS. Just do it from JavaScript, and don't forget to fix the gulf file to copy the js files to the device.